# What figures of speech are common in "roasts"?

Tags: rhetoric, figures-of-speech

When a celebrity or personality is "roasted", lots of bad things are said about and to the (un)fortunate guest; at the end usually there is a change in mood and the person is acknowledged by the reasons that make that person important.

Are there figures of speech that define or explain that style of rhetoric?

Answer (score 2):

Several phrasal verbs – *[make fun of](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/make_fun_of#Verb)*,  *make sport of*, *[poke fun at](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/poke_fun#Verb)* – apply, as well as noun forms of several terms that appear in their definitions [from wiktionary]:
• *[derision](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/derision#Noun)*, “Act of treating with disdain”; derision within a roast is intended to be funny, but more generally is not.
• *[ridicule](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ridicule#Noun)*, “derision; mocking or humiliating words or behaviour”. Again, within a roast it's intended to be funny.
• *[mocking](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mocking#Noun)*, *[teasing](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/teasing#Noun)*, *[taunting](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/taunting#Noun)*
• Phrasal verb *to [put down](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/put_down#Verb)*, “(idiomatic) To [insult](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/insult#Verb), [belittle](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/belittle#Verb), or [demean](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/demean#Verb)”
• *[lampoon](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lampoon#Verb)*, “To satirize or poke fun at”

None of the above terms *explain* a style of rhetoric.  Wikipedia's *[Roast (comedy)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roast_%28comedy%29)* article explains the idea well enough in its opening paragraph:

> A roast is an event in which an individual is subjected to a public presentation of comedic insults, praise, outlandish true and untrue stories, and heartwarming tributes as a mock counter to a toast. The implication is that the roastee is able to take the jokes in good humor and not as serious criticism or insult, and it is seen by some as a great honor to be roasted. The individual is surrounded by friends, fans, and well-wishers, who can receive some of the same treatment as well during the course of the evening...

Jokes at roasts often contain some kernel of truth based on habits of the roastee, with anecdotes exaggerated (via *[hyperbole](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hyperbole#Noun)*, as noted in a comment) or misconstrued for a humorous twist or a [double entendre](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/double_entendre#Noun).

Comment: One figure of speech often utilized is [*hyperbole*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbole).